# How to declare 2 search activities in android manifest

Tags: android, search, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am trying to implement two different searchable activities, one for honeycomb(with search widget) and others for non-honeycomb(with search dialog).

My Manifest looks like:

```
 <activity android:name=".activities.Search" 
                android:theme="@style/NoTitleTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
                    android:enabled="@bool/disableForNonHoneycomb"
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                </intent-filter>
                    <meta-data  android:name="android.app.searchable" 
                        android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                        android:value=".activities.Search"/>
            </activity>
            <activity android:name=".activities.SearchHoneycomb" 
                android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
                    android:enabled="@bool/enableForNonHoneycomb"
                android:launchMode="singleTop">
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
                </intent-filter>
                <meta-data  android:name="android.app.searchable" 
                            android:resource="@xml/searchable"
                            android:value=".activities.SearchHoneycomb"/>
            </activity>
```

And, I use following code to get the searchable configuration and set up the search view in my activity.

```
SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
_searchView = (SearchView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.action_bar_searchwidget);
_searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
```

Problem is that when I use the search widget, it does not start the SearchHoneycomb activity. How can I make this work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, after a lot of investigation... there is no way to have 2 searchable activities as android manifest only accepts 1 meta-data for default-searchable. 
I got a work around by using a search dialog with default-searchable meta-data and the implemented the querytextlistener for search widget.